# git filter-branch --tree-filter results in 'unknown revision or path not in the working tree'

Tags: windows, git, git-filter-branch

my git repository is quite big and I would like to bring its size down by removing some big files, which I added in the past and already removed later on, but which are still in the git history. Now I found the git filter-branch --tree-filter command. So i tried this:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'DEL /content/de/files/bigfile.zip' --all
```

(I'm on Windows).

But the result of invoking this command is:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument '/content/de/files/bigfile.zip'': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

I don't know, what to do. In the current working directory, the file is indeed not present. But it is still there in a couple of old commits in the history. My understanding was, that the command would remove the file from **every** commit.

Comment: You sure you want that leading `/`?

Comment: This is _much_ faster as an index filter, you're not touching content so no need to load the worktree.  `git filter-branch --index-filter 'git update-index --force-remove content/de/files/bigfile.zip' -- --all`

Comment: thanks, will try. To your first comment: I also tried without leading /, but it didn't make a difference.

Comment: hm, tried exactly as you have it above, then it says:  fatal: bad revision 'update-index'

Comment: Ahhh, I have to use " instead of '.

Comment: I think you're using the windows shell, yes? Try using the unix shell, the _vast_ majority of people who understand git work with it exclusively.  There are just too many peerless tools in the unix toolbox, and no reason to reimplement them all.

Comment: ok. last question. After having invoked the command, how do i push to the remote? with push force? Because when doing simple push, it now says, i am behind the remote counterpart.

Comment: Yep. git by default refuses pushes that replace history.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So the actual mistake in my version was, that I used **single** quotes instead of **double** quotes. Seems like, at least on Windows, you have to use those.

That said, the comments from jthill and the answer from Roberto probably present better solutions to the task at hand.

Comment: fatal: bad revision 'checkout'
is the error i got and double quotes fixed it!

Comment: On Windows `git filter-branch` delegates to `git/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-filter-branch` running under MinGW Bash, so running `git` from a Command Prompt will launch Bash, which in turn will launch the command passed to `--filter-xxx` under Bash. Since this is in MinGW the command can be a batch file. Escaping rules are weird, we can use MinGW Bash syntax inside double quotes (properly escaped for Command Prompt, so `--msg-filter` sees the parameter correctly. Note that `\` is not usable inside the `--filter-xxx` parameter because it'll be executed through `eval "$xxx"`, need `\\` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider the BFG,  a faster and simpler alternative to git filter-branch. The equivalent command is :

`$ bfg --delete-files bigfile.zip`

https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/

Disclaimer : I am the author of the BFG